# Can "is" be interchangeable with "has"?

Tags: verbs, lyrics

In these lines from George Harrison's "I Live For You":

> Not a thing in this world do I own
>
> Only sadness from all that is grown

the way I see it I could rewrite it as:

> Not a thing in this world do I own only sadness from all that has grown.

and keep the gist, right?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to the ELL. Where did you find this sentence? It's really awkward. Have a look at the [tour](https://ell.stackexchange.com/tour). Might help you to improve your question.

Comment: And you need to work on your punctuation!

Comment: This is from lyrics: https://www.azlyrics.com/lyrics/georgeharrison/iliveforyou.html

Comment: I don't know who's misguidedly upvoting this, but your example text is ***poetry / lyrics***, not "normal English", featuring syntax that simply wouldn't be used in other contexts, so I think this question is Off Topic.

Answer (score 2):

*All that has grown* is a grammatical phrase, using the verb *grow* in the present perfect construction: referring to things which have grown and whose growth is currently relevant.

*All that is grown* is grammatical but unlikely, because *grown* is here an adjective. *Grown* as an adjective is rare in modern English, and almost entirely restricted to humans: *a grown man*.

If your example is a couple of centuries old, that makes more sense, because in early modern English, *is* could be used for forming perfect constructions for certain. I would not be surprised to read *all that is grown* in text from three hundred years ago; but would not expect it in modern writing.

**Edit**: As @gotube points out, it can be a passive, an interpretation that didn't occur to me.

Answer (score 0):

These are song lyrics, so they don't have to have any meaning, and certainly don't represent how the language is normally used.

And no, changing "is" to "has" would change the meaning.

"*... all that **is** grown*" is in the passive voice, and means everything that people like farmers grow, like food crops and flowers.

"*... all that **has** grown*" is in the present perfect, and means everything that exists in the state it's in now because of some kind of growth, which is much more broad.

Comment: Ah, I didn't think of transitive _grow_, and hence a passive interpretation.